# dataclass containing initalized set?

Tags: python, python-3.x, set, python-3.7, python-dataclasses

I'm trying to use a dataclass for something and in it I need to initialize an empty set, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do it. Before using a dataclass (just regular class) the working equivalent I had was `self.children = set()` and that was fine for my purposes. How can I get that equivalent in a dataclass?

I need it initialized by default, not having to be passed as a parameter each time.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


@dataclass(unsafe_hash=True)
class Node:
    index: int
    name: str
    children: set = field(default_factory=set, hash=True)
```

Error I'm getting when trying to add an item to the set. The item being added is of type Node (the class above).

```
    root.children.add(child)
  File "<string>", line 2, in __hash__
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

Comment: `children: set`?

Comment: Please do show what you tried and why it failed. A comment in code saying you tried stuff doesn't help much...

Comment: Sorry I should have also specified it has to be initialized, not having to be passed as a parameter each time. Added the things I tried as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's:

```
children: set = field(default_factory=set)
```

The default *factory* is a *function* that will be called when initialising the field which returns the initial value. Hence, pass it `set` **without calling it**, which is a function which when called returns a new set. You must also add the `: set` type annotation for the dataclass to pick it up as a field.

Comment: Thank you. I've got one more issue around this I need to fix now, getting an error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'` and I tried adding the `hash=True` option. Being, `children: set = field(default_factory=set, hash=True)` This error happens when I try adding something to the set.

Comment: You get that *when* exactly?

Comment: Sorry edited my comment right after you posted. When I try adding an item to the set, is when I get the error. The item I'm adding is of the class definition above. `children.add(child) # child is of type Node (class above)`

Comment: @Flengo I assume you're trying to add another `Node` instance to the set? Well, the problem there is that `set` is mutable and thus `Node` cannot be safely hashed. You'd first need to define your own logic how a `Node` with mutable `children` can be uniquely hashed. Perhaps just by its `index`? Then implement your own `__hash__` method to implement that logic.